# Python Selenium PhantomJS not clicking on same button that Firefox Webdriver is able to click

Tags: python, selenium

I was implementing a bot to click on upvote button in reddit

Here is the html code of the upvote button.

```html
<div class="arrow up login-required access-required" data-event-action="upvote" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>
<div class="score likes">•</div>
<div class="score unvoted">•</div>
<div class="score dislikes">•</div>
<div class="arrow down login-required access-required" data-event-action="downvote" role="button" aria-label="downvote" tabindex="0"></div>
```

I am able to click on the upvote button using

```html
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='arrow up login-required access-required']")
target.click()


OR

target = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.arrow.up")
target.click()
```

The clicking works fine in FIREFOX web driver , but when I try to implement the same in PhantomJS , the browser is not clicking.

Here is the screenshots of 2 browsers

[image]

Comment: you getting any error ?

Comment: No errors , in fact when I run the code

<code>
print target.text
print target.tag_name
</code>

Both browsers give same reply

Comment: Okk, just for testing. Try it with performing click operation 2 times on phantomjs

Comment: @HassanMehmood I have tried that , no difference.  I tried even 3 times and with a wait too .. still no change

Comment: And did you try it with JavaScript ? using execute_script method of class WebElement.

Comment: @HassanMehmood No , I dont know how to use it for this button

Comment: Okk let me write a sample code for you

Comment: I have posted a sample code in answer, that will click using jquery. Do let me know if that works for you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try performing click() operation via jQuery or JavaScript using execute_script method of selenium. Below is the sample code that will perform the click operation.

```
driver.execute_script("$('div.arrow.up').click()")
```

For the page which has multiple upvote fields then you can use an index to choose which one you want to click e.g

```
driver.execute_script("$('div.arrow.up')[0].click()")
driver.execute_script("$('div.arrow.up')[1].click()")
driver.execute_script("$('div.arrow.up')[2].click()")
and so on..
```

Comment: You are using css selector now right , 

How can we select the element with xpath

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='arrow up login-required access-required']")

because there are lot of div.arrow.ups in the same page sometimes